# Is there a standard Duration String Format for both XSD and JSON formats?

Tags: c#, json, xml, xsd

We are looking to find a common string format for Duration attributes which can be used in both JSON and XML based messages. Is there a standard Duration format that can be used for both?

This is for a B2B protocol where "duration" is a common element. Currently this is implemented only in **XML** so we are creating the XSD using the **xs:duration** element (see **ISO 8601**). We are wanting to include **JSON** as an alternative format but using **xs:duration** strings does not feel natural.

*Personally, I find the XML xs:duration format difficult to read and would like to be rid of it*

XML xs:duration example for 2 minute 45.3 seconds

```xml
<device up-time="PT2M45.3S" />
```

The same value in JSON which is currently using the .NET TimeSpan format

```
 "up-time":"00:02:45.3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one standard for durations and that is the ISO 8601 format (as adopted by XSD). You can use it in JSON if you want.

Sure, it's ugly. Standards are often ugly. If there are business reasons for wanting to sacrifice the benefits of using standards in the interests of aesthetics, then it would be acceptable to use either (a) integer number of seconds, or (b) an xs:time format like 12:30:00 - it's easy enough to convert between these formats. But for a B2B protocol, I would say that standards trump aesthetics.

Making technical decisions affecting a whole industry based on what you describe as "personal feelings" seems inappropriate.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be the answer - I also see from [what-is-a-good-format-for-duration-in-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471779/what-is-a-good-format-for-duration-in-json) question that other people are trying to find a easy to parse and read Duration format for JSON. From a practical point, reading the ISO8601 in .NET requires dependencies on the XML libraries. Although the **xs:time** format seems human friendly, I dont think it is able to handle >24 hours.

Comment: There are many applications for which a simple number (of seconds, or hours, or days) is probably just as good. After all, that's how you represent lengths, weights, voltages, or other units of measure. The only reason we don't have a similar standard for lengths (1Y2F3I = 1 yard 2 feet 3 inches) is that no-one in their right mind uses imperial units any more, so a single decimal number works just fine.