# "TimeSpan" .Net Datatype in API Endpoint not accepting more than 24 hours. throwing validation error

Tags: c#, .net, api, model-view-controller, timespan

Has anyone ever used "TimeSpan" datatype in C#? I am not able to post a value with more than 24 hours to the C# MVC controller. My DTO has a property with "TimeSpan" datatype. I need to give end customer the flexibility of using Timespan. I am now receiving the error in response :

> ""Error converting value "59:42:33" to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.TimeSpan]'.

I am getting the below validation error while posting itself, not even hitting in the C# endpoint..

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0JyV.png)

and the Request json looks like:

{
"timeSinceStarted" : "59:42:33"
}

Comment: Instead of 59 hours, try 2 days and 11 hours (`2.11:42:33`)? The input probably goes to `TimeSpan.TryParse()` with the default format.

Comment: It's probably easier to send the duration (`59:42:33`) converted to milliseconds, then use `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds` to convert to timespan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Json to Serialize/Deserialize TimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232701/using-json-to-serialize-deserialize-timespan)

Comment: @SaifuRahman unfortunately, the two values aren't equal during DST changes. There's no standard for representing durations in JSON. Not even for dates. The ISO8601 date format is a convention, not a standard. Check [What is a good format for Duration in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471779/what-is-a-good-format-for-duration-in-json). You'll have to pick a format that matches *your* requirements. The ISO8601 duration format hasn't caught on though

Comment: @CodeCaster from [What is a good format for Duration in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471779/what-is-a-good-format-for-duration-in-json) `But keep in mind that "PT36H" is not the same as "P1DT12H" when switching from or to Daylight saving time.` The actual quote is from the Wikipedia article on [ISO8601 durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). Haven't thought of that

Comment: @SaifuRahman depending on the library and stack you use you can specify the serialization format eg as a custom type converter in JSON.NET, or a custom binder.

Answer (score 1):

Well this certainly seems strange to me, but I think I have the answer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=net-5.0#System_TimeSpan_Parse_System_String_

> For example, the value of hh, the hours component, must be between 0 and 23. Because of this, passing "23:00:00" to the Parse method returns a time interval of 23 hours. On the other hand, **passing "24:00:00" returns a time interval of 24 days**. Because "24" is outside the range of the hours component, it is interpreted as the days component.

Because of this very strange logic,  apparently, when you specify 24 hours (which becomes 24 days), the minute field is interpreted as hours, which cannot exceed 23. Sure enough, in my test, "24:23:00" is valid (and indeed parses to 24 days, 23 hours), while "24:24:00" is invalid.

This is a bug in my book, but since it's actually documented as correct, it cannot be fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Well, the simplest thing to do is to format this yourself for example code below

**Instead of 59 hours, try 2 days and 11 hours (2.11:42:33)? The input probably goes to TimeSpan.TryParse() with the default format**

Second way

```
return string.Format("{0}hr {1}mn {2}sec",
                 (int) span.TotalHours,
                 span.Minutes,
                 span.Seconds);
```

AND Third way is

```
string span = "35:15";
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(span.Split(':')[0]),    // hours
                       int.Parse(span.Split(':')[1]),    // minutes
                       0);                               // seconds
```

Comment: With your `string.Format()` you've just invented a new TimeSpan format that nobody can parse. And your `new TimeSpan()` code will throw for various formats. Both don't answer the question how you can let MVC parse timespans with > 24 hours.